# Java Simple Chat Box

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I am trying to create a very simple chat window that simply has the ability to display some text, which I add to from time to time.  However I get the following run time error when attempting to append text to the window:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JViewport cannot be cast to javax.swing.JTextPane
    at ChatBox.getTextPane(ChatBox.java:41)
    at ChatBox.getDocument(ChatBox.java:45)
    at ChatBox.addMessage(ChatBox.java:50)
    at ImageTest2.main(ImageTest2.java:160)
```

Here is the class to handle the basic operations:

```
public class ChatBox extends JScrollPane {

private Style style;

public ChatBox() {

    StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
    StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument(context);

    style = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(style, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
    StyleConstants.setSpaceAbove(style, 4);
    StyleConstants.setSpaceBelow(style, 4);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(document);
    textPane.setEditable(false);

    this.add(textPane);
}

public JTextPane getTextPane() {
    return (JTextPane) this.getComponent(0);
}

public StyledDocument getDocument() {
    return (StyledDocument) getTextPane().getStyledDocument();
}

public void addMessage(String speaker, String message) {
    String combinedMessage = speaker + ": " + message;
    StyledDocument document = getDocument();

    try {
        document.insertString(document.getLength(), combinedMessage, style);
    } catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) {
        System.err.println("Oops");
    }
}
}
```

If there is a simpler way to do this, by all means let me know. I only need the text to be of a single font type, and uneditable by the user.  Aside from that, I just need to be able to append text on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Store the `JTextPane` in a member variable and return that inside `getTextPane()`.
2. Modify `getTextPane` to return the `JViewPort`'s view, like this

   ```
   return (JTextPane) getViewport().getView();
   ```

See the [Swing tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more detail.

Also, as camickr (and the tutorials) pointed out, using `add` with a `JScrollPane` is incorrect. You should be either passing the component to the constructor or using [`setViewportView`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView(java.awt.Component)).

<sub>As a side note, I try not to subclass Swing components unless it's absolutely necessary (preferring composition over inheritance). But that's not particularly relevant to the question.</sub>

Comment: I think it's a typo, should be `getView()` not `getViewportView()`.

Comment: @JRL: You're right; I just assumed that the Swing tutorials had it right. That kind of hurts my point about reading them.

Comment: Even though the typo is fixed, the problem is that the text pane has not been added to the viewport, so that will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't extend a JScrollPane. You are NOT adding any functionality to it.

It looks like the basic problem is that your are trying to add the text pane to the scrollpane. This is not the way it works. You need to add the text pane to the viewport. The easy way to do this is:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
```

or

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( textPane );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public JTextPane getTextPane() {
    return (JTextPane) this.getComponent(0);
}
```

`this.getComponent(0)` is returning the ScrollPane's `JViewPort`, not your `JTextPane`. It can't be casted, and so you get your exception.

Comment: This may fix the stated problem, however, the scrollpane won't work since you can't just add the text pane to it. You must add the text pane to the viewport in order for it to work. Then I'm not sure if you are guaranteed that the text pane will be component 0, since you could have scrollbars or row headers added to the scrollpane as well.

Comment: @camickr: I think you're right about the `setViewportView()` part, but note that I'm not proposing a fix, just explaining the exception.